# Codeblocks same output

Tags: c, codeblocks

This problem happened after a while of using Codeblocks[image] , and I'm not able To find an answer on Google , I write whatever on the IDE and I get Always the Same message : hello World and this is the log message and you can see it at the picture , Yes you can say use Visual Studio Code , but I'm studying on Codeblocks because of the school teacher is using it .

I tried to clean install codeblocks , and I even removed Visual Studio Code , and I removed Dotnet after I got that crazy problem .

Comment: why do you put the `main()` in `H1.h`, which is a header file?

Comment: Don't (only) post as images. /// -1073741510, or C000013A in hex, is the code for a program that was forcefully exited using Ctrl-C or by closing the terminal.  /// You're showing a .h file instead of the file you are compiling (which would be a .c file).

Comment: As this file contains code and log messages, this is obviously not the code you compile. Please show the code you compile. Then tell us what output you expect instead of `Hello World`

Comment: '#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
   printf("Resident Evil");
   return 0;
}'

Comment: @ikegami : hey fellow , the code is above this comment , this small code that I try to run , but no success ! I don't know what to do !

Comment: @dustin2022 Thanks , I fixed it , all I had to do is To Go and Create a source file instead of a Header .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thankfully the problem was just me creating a header instead of a source C/C++ , just be careful what you are choosing in the first menu.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67XgA.jpg)